# Go WASM export functions

Tags: go, webassembly

I want to create a `.wasm` file which still has the function names exported when compiled.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main")
}

func MyFunc() {
    fmt.Println("MyFunc")
}
```

I'm building with

```sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
```

Which produces the wasm file (and awesome that Go targets wasm natively).

But using [wabt](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) and doing an object dump exposes these functions.

```sh
Export[4]:
 - func[958] <wasm_export_run> -> "run"
 - func[959] <wasm_export_resume> -> "resume"
 - func[961] <wasm_export_getsp> -> "getsp"
 - memory[0] -> "mem"
```

I'm expecting to see something like

```sh
func[137] <MyFunc> -> "MyFunc"
```

Does anyone know how to export functions in Go WASM?

In rust including `#[no_mangle]` and `pub extern "C"`  keeps the function available in the output with wasm-pack. I'm looking for something similar with Go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you plan to write a lot of WASM in Go, you might want to consider compiling with [TinyGo](https://tinygo.org/), which is a Go compiler for embedded and WASM.

TinyGo supports a `//export <name>` or alias `//go:export <name>` comment directive that does what you're looking for.

I'm copy-pasting the very first example from TinyGo [WASM docs](https://tinygo.org/docs/guides/webassembly/):

```
package main

// This calls a JS function from Go.
func main() {
    println("adding two numbers:", add(2, 3)) // expecting 5
}

// ...omitted

// This function is exported to JavaScript, so can be called using
// exports.multiply() in JavaScript.
//export multiply
func multiply(x, y int) int {
    return x * y;
}
```

And you build it with: `tinygo build -o wasm.wasm -target wasm ./main.go`.

---

The standard Go compiler has an [ongoing open discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25612) about replicating TinyGo feature. The tl;dr seems to be that you can achieve this by setting funcs to the JS global namespace, with the `js.Global().Set(...)`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much thats done it! Compiling with TinyGo yeilds
`- func[146] <MyFunc> -> "MyFunc"`