# Calling a function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, go

Trying to understand wasm in go, so I wrote the below that:

1. Manipulate DOM
2. Call JS function
3. Define a function that can called by JS

first 2 steps are fine, but the last one is not working as expected, as I got the JavaScript error `function undefined`, my code is below, the issue I have is in the function `sub`

```golang
package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
)

// func sub(a, b float64) float64

func sub(this js.Value, inputs []js.Value) interface{} {
    return inputs[0].Float() - inputs[1].Float()
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int) // channel to keep the wasm running, it is not a library as in rust/c/c++, so we need to keep the binary running
    js.Global().Set("sub", js.FuncOf(sub))
    alert := js.Global().Get("alert")
    alert.Invoke("Hi")
    println("Hello wasm")

    num := js.Global().Call("add", 3, 4)
    println(num.Int())

    document := js.Global().Get("document")
    h1 := document.Call("createElement", "h1")
    h1.Set("innerText", "This is H1")
    document.Get("body").Call("appendChild", h1)

    <-c // pause the execution so that the resources we create for JS keep available
}
```

compiled it to wasm as:

```sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm wasm.go
```

Copied the `wasm_exec.js` file to the same working folder as:

```sh
cp "$(go env GOROOT)/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js" .
```

My HTML file is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WASM</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/www/lib.js"></script>
    <!-- WASM -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/www/wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/www/loadWasm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
   console.log(sub(5,3));
</script>
</html>
```

The `lib.js` is:

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

The `loadWasm.js` is:

```
async function init(){
    const go = new Go();
    const result = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/www/main.wasm"),
        go.importObject
    );
    go.run(result.instance);
}
init();
```

The server code is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func wasmHandler() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("www/home.html"))

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        err := tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    })
}

func main() {
    fs := http.StripPrefix("/www/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./www")))
    http.Handle("/www/", fs)

    http.Handle("/home", wasmHandler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

The output i got is:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried using the TinyGO example as below, but got almost the same issue:

```golang
//wasm.go

package main

// This calls a JS function from Go.
func main() {
    println("adding two numbers:", add(2, 3)) // expecting 5
}

// module from JavaScript.
func add(x, y int) int

//export multiply
func multiply(x, y int) int {
    return x * y
}
```

Compliled it as:

```sh
tinygo build -o main2.wasm -target wasm -no-debug
cp "$(tinygo env TINYGOROOT)/targets/wasm_exec.js" .
```

And `server.go` as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

const dir = "./www"

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))
    log.Print("Serving " + dir + " on http://localhost:8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        resp.Header().Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        if strings.HasSuffix(req.URL.Path, ".wasm") {
            resp.Header().Set("content-type", "application/wasm")
        }
        fs.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
    }))
}
```

And the JS code as:

```
const go = new Go(); // Defined in wasm_exec.js

go.importObject.env = {
    'main.add': function(x, y) {
        return x + y
    }
    // ... other functions
}


const WASM_URL = 'main.wasm';

var wasm;

if ('instantiateStreaming' in WebAssembly) {
    WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(WASM_URL), go.importObject).then(function (obj) {
        wasm = obj.instance;
        go.run(wasm);
    })
} else {
    fetch(WASM_URL).then(resp =>
        resp.arrayBuffer()
    ).then(bytes =>
        WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, go.importObject).then(function (obj) {
            wasm = obj.instance;
            go.run(wasm);
        })
    )
}

// Calling the multiply function:
console.log('multiplied two numbers:', exports.multiply(5, 3));
```

And the output i got is:
[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978442/go-wasm-export-functions/67983256#67983256

Comment: The function is available *after* the wasm main runs. Try using a script embedded in the body to start the wasm, instead of using an async function.

Comment: @blackgreen kindly see my update

Comment: @BurakSerdar kindly see my update

Comment: @HasanAYousef I think the problem after the update is that you don't wait for your setup Promises before calling `exports.multiply`. If you move the call to `multiply()` into the `.then` functions right after the calls to `go.run`, it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, that I need something to detect and confirm that `wasm` had been loaded and ready for processing, same the one used in JS to check if the document is ready:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  // The page is fully loaded
}

// or

document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    // document ready
  }
};
```

So, as `wasm` initiation function in my code is `async` I used the below in JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WASM</title>
    <!-- WASM -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/www/wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/www/loadWasm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    (async () => {
        try {
            await init();
            alert("Wasm had been loaded")
            console.log(multiply(5, 3));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        } 
    })(); 

/***** OR ****/
    (async () => {
        await init();
        alert("Wasm had been loaded")
        console.log(multiply(5, 3));
    })().catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
/*************/
</script>
</html>
```

This helped me been sure that the document is ready to process and call the wasm function.

The `wasm` loading function simply became:

```
async function init(){
    const go = new Go();
    const result = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/www/main.wasm"),
        go.importObject
    );
    go.run(result.instance); 
}
```